# Using linear storage to implement a 2D array

Tags: c++, memory, multidimensional-array, storage

I need to create a function that helps to implement a 2D array using linear storage in C++. The first of these functions is `two_d_store()`, which takes as arguments the following: base address in memory of region to be used as 2D array, size in bytes of an array entry, 2 array dimensions, and 2 index values. So with this `two_d_store()` function:

```
int d[10][20];
d[4][0] = 576;
```

can be replaced with

```
char d[200*sizeof(int)];
two_d_store(d, sizeof(int), 10, 20, 4, 0, 576);
```

So is there a simple way to implement this function without using arrays?

Comment: Any reason why you are not using `int d[200];`?

Comment: @RSahu No that's how the problem is stated, it also confused me a little as to why they did that

Comment: What have you tried? Just use some math to figure out the location to store the number, slice the number with some bit operations, and put it in the array. Be more specific on why you need help. http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: @FeiXiang So even with linear storage its not possible to do without using atleast a 1D array?

Comment: What do you mean without an array? Isn't this function supposed to be called on an array? If you mean the function not having to make it's own array, the answer is yes, you can do it. You shouldn't need another array in the function.

Comment: This is not right: `char d[200*sizeof(int)];` It might align the improperly. You need `int d[200];`

Comment: If `d` is a `char*`, this is not right either: `two_d_store(d, sizeof(int), 10, 20, 4, 0, 576);`. If that is part of the problem statement, I don't know what to tell you.  Tell us exactly what the assignment is, verbatim.

Comment: In other words, this is an XY problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem  We'll need the X..

Comment: Are you still there? Are you typing out the assignment?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the last argument to a pointer, not value, bcs we don't know what type it is. The max_y param is not needed. First i compute on n_array_ptr  the adress of cell we want to change, and then memcpy the size_of_type bytes from new_value pointer to n_array_ptr. This function can be used for arrays of all types, bcs we are casting it void* and calculating the adress of block where our cell starts, and copy'ing exectly size_of_type bytes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

void two_d_store(void * array_ptr, size_t size_of_type, int max_y, int max_x, int y, int x, void* new_value) {
    void * n_array_ptr = array_ptr + size_of_type * (y * max_x + x);
    memcpy(n_array_ptr, new_value, size_of_type);
}

int main() {
    int d[10*20];
    int new_val = 576;
    two_d_store(d, sizeof(int), 10, 20, 4, 0, &new_val);
    cout<<d[4*20]; //[4][20]
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For any weird or not reason, if u dont want to have the standard way to access or set your memory structs, you could use 
`memcpy(void *dst, const void *src, size_t len);`
Its a C function but it works 100% for C++ too.

Here are some general memory handling functions i found, good luck!:

```
void *memchr(const void *ptr, int ch, size_t len)
```

memchr finds the first occurence of ch in ptr and returns a pointer to it (or a null pointer if ch was not found in the first len bytes

```
int memcmp(const void *ptr1, const void *ptr2, size_t len)
```

memcmp is similar to strcmp, except that bytes equal to 0 are not treated as comparison terminators.

```
void *memcpy(void *dst, const void *src, size_t len)
```

memcpy copies len characters from src to dst and returns the original value of dst
The result of memcpy is undefined if src and dst point to overlapping areas of memory

```
void *memmove(void *dst, const void *src, size_t len)
```

memmove is just like memcpy except that memmove is guaranteed to work even if the memory areas overlap

```
void *memset(void *ptr, int byteval, size_t len)
```

memset sets the first len bytes of the memory area pointed to by ptr to the value specified by byteval